# How do I get a US document notarised from overseas?

Tags: united-states, international, notaries

How do I get a United States document (for business, to be sent to the USA) notarised and apostilled in the Netherlands?

Comment: https://nl.usembassy.gov/u-s-citizen-services/notary-services/ If this is a US document, it doesn't need to be apostilled. https://nl.usembassy.gov/u-s-citizen-services/local-resources/apostilles/

Comment: If you use a Dutch notary, and it turns out you really do need an apostille, see https://www.hcch.net/en/instruments/conventions/authorities1/?cid=41 for which government official can do this. Notaries in Europe should be well-trained in this and be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

You could go to your local U.S. embassy, or you could go to your neighborhood Dutch notary. Usually a notarization by a foreign notary will be valid on a U.S. document.